# Как посчитать количество рукопожатий между пользователями ВКонтакте?

Tags: алгоритм, вконтакте, графы

Появилась необходимость посчитать количество рукопожатий между пользователями ВКонтакте. Есть граф в виде словаря {id_пользователя: список_id_его_друзей, ...}. Какой алгоритм поиска кратчайшего пути в графе оптимально использовать для решения данной задачи? Конечно, чем проще и быстрее алгоритм, тем лучше. Необходимо знать только число рукопожатий. (Расстояние от одной вершины графа до другой)

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Навскидку: https://intuit.ru/studies/courses/648/504/lecture/11475?page=1